# No line here to end inside custom environment

Tags: line-breaking, environments

I wrote an "advanced" environment, but I am having problems if I put another environment inside:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newif\ifadvanced % advanced environment
\advancedtrue % comment out to hide advanced environments


\newcommand{\separator}{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}}
\newenvironment{advanced}{\ifadvanced\par\separator \small \fi}{\ifadvanced\\\separator\par\fi}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=-6pt,%
  spacebelow=6pt,%
  headfont=\normalfont\itshape,%
  postheadspace=1em,%
  qed=\qedsymbol%
]{myproofstyle} 
\declaretheorem[name={Proof},style=myproofstyle,unnumbered,
]{advancedproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{advanced}
Inside advanced environment.
\begin{advancedproof}
inside proof
\end{advancedproof}
\end{advanced}
\end{document}
```

I could fix this problem by adding text between `\end{advanced}` and `\end{advancedproof}` but there must be a better way to solve this problem. I can't seem to find the answer, as I tried to add newlines inside the environments without luck.

**UPDATE**

The proposed code messes up the behavior where there is no inner environment:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newif\ifadvanced % advanced environment
\advancedtrue % comment out to hide advanced environments


\newif\ifadvanced % advanced environment
\advancedtrue % comment out to hide advanced environments


\newcommand{\separator}{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}}
\newenvironment{advanced}{\ifadvanced\par\separator \small \fi}{\ifadvanced\vspace*{-1em}\separator\par\fi}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=-6pt,%
  spacebelow=6pt,%
  headfont=\normalfont\itshape,%
  postheadspace=1em,%
  qed=\qedsymbol%
]{myproofstyle} 
\declaretheorem[name={Proof},style=myproofstyle,unnumbered,
]{advancedproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{advanced}
Inside advanced environment.
\begin{advancedproof}
inside proof
\end{advancedproof}
\end{advanced}


\begin{advanced}
Inside advanced environment. But without any other internal environment
\end{advanced}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem is `\ifadvanced\\ ` which you should replace, e.g. with `\ifadvanced\hbox{}\\ ` or something else properly ending the environment.

Comment: I don't have much experience defining environments. I had to use a flag to be able to remove advanced environments and thus I made it work using the code above. Do you have an example of what you mean by properly ending the environment?

Comment: I meant something which does not prevent the line break, e.g. a `\vspace*{}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace your code with the following. This just translates `\\` to `\vspace*{0pt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm} % For math equations, theorems, symbols, etc
\usepackage{thmtools}

\newif\ifadvanced % advanced environment
\advancedtrue % comment out to hide advanced environments


\newcommand{\separator}{\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\rule{\linewidth}{0.4pt}}}
\newenvironment{advanced}{\ifadvanced\par\separator \small \fi}{\ifadvanced\vspace*{0pt}\separator\par\fi}

\declaretheoremstyle[%
  spaceabove=-6pt,%
  spacebelow=6pt,%
  headfont=\normalfont\itshape,%
  postheadspace=1em,%
  qed=\qedsymbol%
]{myproofstyle} 
\declaretheorem[name={Proof},style=myproofstyle,unnumbered,
]{advancedproof}

\begin{document}

\begin{advanced}
Inside advanced environment.
\begin{advancedproof}
inside proof
\end{advancedproof}
\end{advanced}
\end{document}
```

*Update:* Your problem should be solved using

```
\newenvironment{advanced}{\ifadvanced\par\separator \small \fi}{\ifadvanced\vspace*{-.75em}\par\separator\par\fi}
```

Comment: In this way though, there is a big space between the last line of the advanced environment and the separator.

Comment: @aaragon You can of course adjust the value used (even negative). It's a vspace-command!

Comment: Still it doesn't work. If I have no environment inside then it breaks! Look at the update.

Comment: @aaragon I've updated my answer (last lines) to meet your needs. If you have another `\parskip` please adjust the vspace.